# How To Change Image Height Using a Variable?

Tags: javascript, image, normalization, frequency

I had to create a frequency count of each letter that occurs in a sentence. That frequency is than put in a chart. We take this 1px by 1px gif and stretch it to reach the normalized value (max 100px) of the current letters frequency. For example if I had the phrase "Cwm fjord bank glyphs vext quiz" each letter would have 100px since it uses every letter only once.

So I created an array to sort the times each word comes in. Then find out which word occurs the most times so that I know what I will have to divide each word by. The value will be the height of the image when I make it.

```
function htmlChart() {
    var table = document.getElementById("table");
    input = document.getElementById("userInput").value;
    table.innerHTML = generateTable(input);
}

function generateTable(input) {
    var frequency = new Array(26);
    var letters = new Array(26);
    var freqPos = 0;
    var newInput = input.toUpperCase();
    var max = 0;
    var myHeight = 0;
    var test = 9000;
    var image = new Image();
    image.src = "orange.gif";
    for (i = 65; i < 91; i++) {
        //looks at how many times each character occurs and stores its value
        frequency[freqPos] = newInput.split(String.fromCharCode(i)).length -
            1;
        freqPos++;
    }
    //checks which letter occured the most
    for (i = 0; i < frequency.length - 1; i++) {
        if (frequency[i] > max) {
            max = frequency[i];
        }
    }

    table = input + "<table>";
    //first row 
    table += "<tr>";
    table += "<td>Letter Frequency 100px</td>";
    for (i = 0; i < frequency.length - 1; i++) {
        //somehow have to use myHeight to change the height of the image that I make here. 
        myHeight = (frequency[i] / max) * 100;
        table +=
            '<td><img src = "orange.gif" id = "orange" alt = "25" height = myHeight + "px" width = "5"></td>';
    }
    table += "</tr>";
    //second row
    table += "<tr>";
    table += "<td></td>";
    for (i = 65; i < 91; i++) {
        table += "<td>" + String.fromCharCode(i) + "</td>";
    }
    table += "</tr>";
    table += "</table>";
    return table;
}
```

So as you can see I have already made the frequency chart, but I just don't know how I can change the height to the value of myHeight. Could someone explain how I would have to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the concatenation is off. Change this

```
'<td><img src = "orange.gif" id = "orange" alt = "25" height = myHeight + "px" width = "5"></td>';
```

to

```
'<td><img src = "orange.gif" id = "orange" alt = "25" height="' + myHeight + 'px" width = "5"></td>';
```

Note that each string that's being concatenated is delimited by a single quote `'`.